# Выполнение python-скрипта на сервере

Tags: python, opencv, openserver

Хочу запустить данный python-скрипт на сервере:

```
#!C:\Users\Username\Anaconda3\python.exe
import cgi

print("Content-type: text/html\n")
print("""<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>""")

import cv2
import os

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(3, 640)  # set video width
cam.set(4, 480)  # set video height

face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml')

# For each person, enter one numeric face id
face_id = 1

print("\n [INFO] Initializing face capture. Look the camera and wait ...")
# Initialize individual sampling face count
count = 0

while (True):

    ret, img = cam.read()
    # img = cv2.flip(img, -1)  # flip video image vertically
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    count += 1

    # Save the captured image into the datasets folder
    cv2.imwrite("dataset/User." + str(face_id) + '.' + str(count) + ".jpg", gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])

    cv2.imshow('image', img)

k = cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xff  # Press 'ESC' for exiting video
if k == 27:
    break
elif count >= 30:  # Take 30 face sample and stop video
    break

# Do a bit of cleanup
print("\n [INFO] Exiting Program and cleanup stuff")
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("""</body>
    </html>""")
```

Страница рендерится, но библиотека cv2 не импортируется.
После импорта библиотеки выполнение скрипта заканчивается.
Как можно исправить это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не импортируются с какой-то ошибкой? Если да, приведите её в вопросе.

Comment: Без ошибок. Просто сv2 не импортируется. После строчки import сv2 выполнение скрипта заканчивается.

Comment: Откуда тогда Вы узнали, что он не импортируется?

Comment: print(cv2.__version__)

Comment: *После импорта библиотек выполнение скрипта заканчивается* отладчиком проходили? Уверены, что ни один оператор после импорта не выполняется и при этом программа завершается без исключений?

Comment: У себя в ide проверил, скрипт полностью выполнялся. Как на сервере запустил, сразу такие "ошибки возникли". Может быть сv2 надо как-то с сервером связать?
Не знаю

Comment: V-Mor, Добавил картинку с ошибками

Comment: @Данила Ну, там написано, что с установкой библиотеки `Numpy` у вас какие-то проблемы, а `cv2` внутри себя `Numpy` использует. Возникает вопрос - что за сервер, если он `DLL` файлы грузит, на винде что ли?

Comment: Вопрос с Numpy был решён. Да, винда.

Comment: @Данила А у вас нет возможности в консоли попробовать сначала запустить, а не через страницу веб-сервера? Гораздо проще ошибки смотреть в консоли. Вот так по козябрам ничего непонятно, в чём теперь проблема.

Comment: @CrazyElf В консоли как раз не выдаёт никаких ошибок и нормально скрипт работает.

Comment: @Данила А в консоли питон точно из того же окружения запускается? Вообще, посмотрите логи веб-сервера хотя бы, а не страницу, которую он выдаёт. В логах возможно нормально написано, без козябр. Ну или можно перекодировать

Comment: @CrazyElf Перекодировал, там написано: "Не найден указанный модуль"

Comment: @Данила Ну в общем надо разбираться - оттуда ли питон на веб-сервере запускается откуда и в консоли. Те же ли ему переменные окружения передаются и т.д. Питонов на компе может быть несколько штук. И окружений внутри анаконды может быть несколько настроено.

Comment: @CrazyElf Как это можно проверить?

Comment: @Данила Ну, проверить что в PATH и т.д., проверить версия питона какая запустилась и т.д. Я не силён в настройках веб-серверов вообще.